# "Use the new keyword if hiding was intended" warning

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a warning at the bottom of my screen:

> Warning   1   'WindowsFormsApplication2.EventControlDataSet.Events' hides
>   inherited member
>   'System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent.Events'. Use the new
>   keyword if hiding was intended.   C:\Users\myComputer\Desktop\Event
>   Control\WindowsFormsApplication2\EventControlDataSet.Designer.cs  112 32  eventControl

If i double click on it, it comes up with:

```
public EventsDataTable Events {
    get {
        return this.tableEvents;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Your class has a base class, and this base class also has a property (which is not virtual or abstract) called Events which is being overridden by your class. If you intend to override it put the "new" keyword after the public modifier. E.G.

```
public new EventsDataTable Events
{
  ..
}
```

If you don't wish to override it change your properties' name to something else.

Comment: [Here is a link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6576212/3156863) for anyone  who wants to know  what the *difference* between new and override is.

Comment: The `new`  keyword would get rid of the compilation error, but may introduce other unintended behavior. I think you should add a warning to your answer. That would be helpful for understanding the consequences of adding `new`.

Answer (score 13):

@wdavo is correct. The same is also true for functions.

If you override a base function, like Update, then in your subclass you need:

```
new void Update()
{
  //do stufff
}
```

Without the new at the start of the function decleration you will get the warning flag.

Comment: What is the purpose of using 'new' keyword as even without using the 'new' keyword the result is same, i.e., the base class method implementation is not invoked.

Answer (score 10):

In the code below, `Class A` implements the interface `IShow` and implements its method `ShowData`. `Class B` inherits `Class A`. In order to use `ShowData` method in `Class B`, we have to use keyword `new` in the `ShowData` method in order to hide the base class `Class A` method and use `override` keyword in order to extend the method.

```
interface IShow
{
    protected void ShowData();
}

class A : IShow
{
    protected void ShowData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is Class A");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    protected new void ShowData()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is Class B");
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no `override` in your example from your explication and `override` is not needed.

Comment: I think your example is on the right track, but is incomplete. Also your explanation is unclear. Could you edit your answer to be something more like https://dotnetfiddle.net/Iw0OzB? If not I'll probably post my fiddle as another answer

Answer (score 2):

The parent function needs the `virtual` keyword, and the child function needs the `override` keyword in front of the function definition.

Answer (score 1):

this warning also triggers when you have: 
 `x:Name="Name1"` with `Text="{Binding Name1}"` **the Same Property Name** in same Element in your `<Xaml>` 
 which can cause a serious conflict at a certain point when your binding process become more complex.