# How do I turn off the warning "use the new keyword if hiding was intended"?

Tags: c#, .net-core, project.json

Ref: ["Use the new keyword if hiding was intended" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193821/use-the-new-keyword-if-hiding-was-intended-warning)

This time, the warning needs to go away without editing file to add the new keyword.

Why? Generated derived class.

Comment: Yeah I can pull off the #pragma if I know which one it is.

Comment: Incidentally the behavior is expected to my old-school C++ mind.

Comment: Do you have control over the file generator? Can you do some automatic post-processing to add the keyword where necessary?

Comment: @derpirscher: Too hard and breaks loose coupling.

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `#pragma warning disable 108` at the top of the file where you want the warning disabled.