# Difference in replacing "new" with "override" keyword

Tags: c#, overriding

Please find the code below:

```
using System;

namespace MainNS
{
    abstract class BaseClass
    {
        abstract public void fun();
     }

    class DerivedClass1 : BaseClass
    {
        override public void fun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fun() of DerivedClass1 invoked!");
        }

    }

    class DerivedClass2 : DerivedClass1
    {
        new public void fun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fun() of DerivedClass2 invoked!");
        }

    }

    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DerivedClass1 d1 = new DerivedClass2();
            d1.fun();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

}
```

What is the use of replacing `new` with `override` here and Please explain the actual concept behind this.

`Override` keyword makes `fun()` of `DerivedClass2` to be executed and `new` keyword makes `fun()` of `DerivedClass1` to be executed.

```
 class DerivedClass2 : DerivedClass1
   {
        new public void fun()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("fun() of DerivedClass2 invoked!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for bad english!!

Answer (score 0):

The following page summarizes your question very nicely.

[Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153(v=vs.80).aspx)

**Summary**

**Override**: When a method of a base class is overridden in a derived class, the version in the derived class is used, even if the calling code didn't "know" that the object was an instance of the derived class.

**New**: If you use the new keyword instead of override, the method in the derived class doesn't override the method in the base class, it merely hides it.

If you don't specify either new or overrides, the resulting output is the same as if you specified new, but you'll also get a compiler warning (as you may not be aware that you're hiding a method in the base class method, or indeed you may have wanted to override it, and merely forgot to include the keyword).

**Override**: used with virtual/abstract/override type of method in base class

**New**: when base class has not declared method as virtual/abstract/override

[New Vs Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576206/what-is-the-difference-between-the-override-and-new-keywords-in-c)

Comment: Does fun() of DerivedClass1 act as a virtual/abstract method because it is overriden by fun() of DerivedClass2. No keyword (virtual/abstract) was mentioned in DerivedClass1 btw.