# C# - Polymorphism confusing overloading and method hiding

Tags: c#

I have a class named `Item` which acts as an abstract class, but is not defined as one. This class has a `MaxPerStack` property:

```
public class Item
{
    public short MaxPerStack
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Data.MaxPerStack;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a class named `Equip` which derives from the `Item` class and also has a property named `MaxPerStack` which is declared as `new`:

```
public class Equip : Item
{
    public new short MaxPerStack
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following method called `Add`, which uses the `MaxPerStack` property of `item`:

```
public void Add(Item item)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Stack: {0}.", item.MaxPerStack);
}
```

When I do:

```
Add(new Equip());
```

It goes to the `MaxPerStack` property of `Item` rather to the `Equip` one.

Why's that happening?

Comment: you should use a real abstract class and/or virtual methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576206/what-is-the-difference-between-the-override-and-new-keywords-in-c

Comment: @DanielA.White I cannot make `Item` abstract as I'm creating instances of this class.

Comment: `I have a class named Item which acts as an abstract class, but is not defined as one.` why? `It goes to the MaxPerStack property of Item rather to the Equip one.` that's because that's what you told it to do. All it knows is that `item` is an `Item`, it doesn't know it's an `Equip`. And since `MaxPerStack` isn't virtual, it calls the one in `Item`.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams then you should make it `virtual`

Comment: You need to show us more info. What class owns the `Add(Item)` method. Show us how you are isntancing the object, so we can see what object you are calling `.Add` on.

Comment: @GilbertWilliams if you are creating instances, then you need to make an even higher class, which then is really abstract.

Comment: You are confusing the concept of abstract. Don't call `Item` an abstract class, as abstract means it can not be instanced and it potentially contains members that must be implemented. Instead, call it what it is - a base class.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger None of the information you've said is missing is relevant or necessary to explain the behavior in question.

Comment: @JohnathonSullinger He specifically shows the call site of the method: `Add(new Equip());`, so we know that the parameter really is an `Equip` instance.  We don't need to know anything about the type that the `Add` method is in, as none of the other members of that class, or any details about the class itself, are going to affect the behavior shown here, and there is already enough information to explain the behavior seen.  One could make the example a *touch* better by removing that not-named type from the example entirely, but what's there is fine.

Comment: @Servy I misread the implementation of the `Add` method, my mistake. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5):

Because you didn't mark `Item.MaxPerStack` as `virtual`, and you didn't mark `Equip.MaxPerStack` as `override`.  You need to do *both* of those things to get the behavior you're expecting.

By implicitly marking the base type's method as `sealed` and explicitly marking the derived type as `new` you're preventing virtual dispatch, which is the exact mechanism that is used to ensure that a method called on the base type will execute the implementation associated with the actual *runtime type* of the object, rather than statically binding the method to the implementation in the *compile time* type of the object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your `Equip` class replaces the `MaxPerStack` property defined on the `Item` class.

```
public class Equip : Item
{
    public new short MaxPerStack
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

MSDN tells you that:

> If the method in the derived class is preceded with the new keyword, the method is defined as being independent of the method in the base class.
>
> ..
>
> Using the new keyword tells the compiler that your definition hides the definition that is contained in the base class. This is the default behavior.

This applies to properties as well. This tells you that the `Equip` will have it's own, non-related, version of `MaxPerStack`. So when you call `Item.MaxPerStack` you are accessing the property on the `Item` class, and not the `Equip` class. Regardless if the `Item` you pass in is actually an `Equip` class.

To solve this, you can make the `MaxPerStack` property virtual, then override it in the `Equip` class.

```
public class Item
{
    public virtual short MaxPerStack
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Data.MaxPerStack;
        }
    }
}

public class Equip : Item
{
    public override short MaxPerStack
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you provide `Equip` as the parameter to `Add(Item)`, the `Add` method will access the `MaxPerStack` property on the `Equip` class instead.

MSDN tells you this:

> If the method in the derived class is preceded with the override keyword, objects of the derived class will call that method instead of the base class method.