# String interpolation in C# 6 and overridden ToString()

Tags: c#, string, c#-6.0

Given the following classes:

```
public abstract class ValueBase
{
    public new abstract string ToString();
}

public class EmailAddress : ValueBase
{
    public MailAddress MailAddress { get; }

    public EmailAddress([NotNull] string address)
    {
        MailAddress = new MailAddress(address);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return MailAddress.Address;
    }
}
```

Why does:

```
var email = new EmailAddress("joe@bloggs.com");

string emailString1 = $"{email}";
string emailString2 = email.ToString();
```

return a string of the type name (`Namespace.EmailAddress`), not the overridden ToString method (`joe@bloggs.com`)?

Comment: It is asking for trouble to create a **new** `ToString` method hiding the `Object.ToString` method that all types have.

Comment: What is the code of `MailAddress`?

Comment: You have two string there.

Comment: Use 'public abstract override string ToString();' in your base class.

Comment: Why define `ToString` at all in the base class if it doesn't really override anything? The only valid use I can think of is it to *force* implementers to override `ToString`?

Comment: You are right @PanagiotisKanavos - it was to force the implementation of ToString in classes which inherit the base class. Changing it to `public abstract override string ToString();` fixed my issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, `$"{email}"` string is automatically converted to `string.Format("{0}", email)` and this method's second parameter is of type `params object[]`. So it upcasts all values to `object` before invoking `ToString()` method. In your code you simply replace this method with new one inside `ValueBase` class, and `override` keyword inside `EmailAddress` class implements this abstract method and not the original object's one.

You can easily test it if you cast your second value to object explicitly :

```
var email = new EmailAddress("joe@bloggs.com");

string emailString1 = $"{email}";
string emailString2 = ((object)email).ToString();
```

As you can see now `emailString2` returns typename as well. You can remove `ToString()` method from abstract class and let `EmailAdress` class to implement object's `ToString()` or implement it there in abstract class. For example :

```
    public abstract class ValueBase
    {
        // overrides object's ToString()
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return base.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class EmailAddress : ValueBase
    {
       ...

       // overrides ValueBase's ToString()
       public override string ToString()
       {
           return MailAddress.Address;
       }
    }
```

With this new code the output is as expected :

```
joe@bloggs.com
joe@bloggs.com
```

Comment: Coupled with `public override abstract string ToString();` on the base type and it's working as expected. Thanks.

Comment: What is the point of the no-op override in the abstract class?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's to force the subclass to provide a `ToString` implementation

Answer (score 25):

Interpolation works as expected since your classes do *not* override `Object.ToString()`. `ValueBase` defines a *new* method that *hides* `Object.ToString` instead of overriding it.

Simply remove `ToString` from `ValueBase`. In this case `Email.Address` will override `Object.ToString` correctly, and interpolation will return the desired result.

Specifically, changing ValueBase to this:

```
public abstract class ValueBase
{
}
```

Makes the test code

```
var email = new EmailAddress("joe@bloggs.com");
string emailString1 = $"{email}";
```

return `joe@bloggs.com`

**UPDATE**

As people suggested, the base `ToString()` method could be added to force implementers to implement a custom `ToString` method in their classes. This can be achieved by defining an `abstract override` method.

```
public abstract class ValueBase
{
    public abstract override string ToString();
}
```

Comment: It seems the OP wants to enforce a custom implementation of the `ToString` method. The easiest way would be to override `ToString` to call some *other* abstract method.

Comment: @Luaan nope, the easiest way would be `public abstract override string ToString();`

Answer (score 3):

```
string emailString1 = $"{email}"; //call the Object.ToString() method
string emailString2 = email.ToString();//call your overrided ValueBase.ToString() method
```

Actually $"" Ultimately are using a internal method in the class StringBuilder.

StringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, string format, ParamsArray args)

The key code:

```
 object obj = args[index3];
 //... bilibili About On Line 1590
  else if (obj != null)
    str = obj.ToString();// So it use the object.ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, hiding `ToString` is asking for trouble, dont do it; it is pretty confusing that `string.Format("{0}", email)` or `$"{email}` prints out something different than `email.ToString()`.

Second, `emailString1` and `emailString2` can not be the same as you claim. The output of `email.ToString()` is `"joe@bloggs.com"`, the output of `$"{email}"` is `"{namespace}.EmailAddress"`.

Why the difference? It's because you are *hiding* `ToString` in `ValueBase`. A call of the type `EmailAddress.ToString` (a call through an `EmailAddress` typed reference) will call the new implementation of `ToString` but a call `Object.ToString` (a call through an `object` typed reference) will call the implementation in `Object`; `$"{email}"` is equivalent to `string.Format("{0}", email)` which is morally equivalent to `string.Format("{0}", (object)mail)` so you are really invoking `ToString` form an object typed reference;

What you need to do is *override* `ToString` and you will get the expected behavior:

```
public abstract class ValueBase
{
    public override abstract string ToString();
}
```

Any call to an `EmailAddress.ToString`, no mater the type of the reference will call the overriden implementation.

Note that you seem to be conflating *new* and *override*:

> Why does ... return a string of the type name `(Namespace.EmailAddress)`, not the overridden `ToString` method (`joe@bloggs.com`)?

You are not *overriding* `ToString`, you are *hiding* it. To see the difference between `new` and `override` read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576206/what-is-the-difference-between-the-override-and-new-keywords-in-c).