# Why does new "hide" the base class method?

Tags: c#

I have a problem with terminology. According to MSDN: "The override modifier extends the base class method, and the new modifier hides it."
However, in the following example:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual void Method1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base - Method1");
        }
    }

    class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public void Method1() // DerivedClass.Method1() hides inherited memeber BaseClass.Method1(). Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method1");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BaseClass bd = new DerivedClass();
            bd.Method1();
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

You will see that if you use **new** in declaring Method1() in DerivedClass, bd.Method1() will output: "Base - Method1" as instructed in the base class.

...whereas, if you use **override** in declaring Method1() in DerivedClass, bd.Method1() will output: "Derived - Method1" as instructed in the derived class.

Why does every source (including the official documentation) say that **new** **hides** the **base** class method, when clearly in this example the base class method is the one invoked when using new?

I understand the different behaviours (new compared to override) but not the terminology.

Comment: check this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/knowing-when-to-use-override-and-new-keywords, for `hiding`, `new` should be there in the method definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the override and new keywords in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576206/what-is-the-difference-between-the-override-and-new-keywords-in-c)

Comment: It hides it in the DerivedClass (and any descendants of it). It doesn't hide it in BaseClass. So yes, it does really hide the base class method, but that does not mean what you obviously think it does. See my answer too.

Comment: `new` does nothing to your output here. It only suppresses a warning. It's just terminology, in VB the equivalent keyword is `Hides`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several uses of `new`. The one mentioned in the docs you refer to is the declaration modifier.

Your `Method1()` in the derived class can be declared in three ways:

```
public void Method1()         // 1
public new void Method1()     // 2
public virtual void Method1() // 3
```

Both version 1 and 2 **hide** the virtual method of the same name in the base class, so when called on a base class variable, `BaseClass.Method1()` will be called. But version 2 (with `new`) **explicitly** hides the base class method, i.e. *you are telling the compiler that this was intentional*. Version 1 **implicitly** hides the virtual method and will result in a warning, because the compiler assumes it could be accidental, and not intentional.

**Hiding** does not mean what you think it does. It means that in `DerivedClass` and any descendants of it, `Method1()` is not virtual and that you *can't call the virtual method* on a `DerivedClass` anymore. They say that the *virtual* method is hidden from `DerivedClass`. That means it breaks (inheritance) polymorphism.

Version 3 **overrides** the method of the same name, and if a method is virtual, the *actual* method will be called, no matter how the variable is declared. So if the variable is declared as `BaseClass`, but in reality the class is a `DerivedClass`, then the derivate's method will be called.

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier

Note that that use of `new` is not the same as what you understood:

```
BaseClass bd = new DerivedClass();
```

That is a different `new`, and *not the declaration modifier*.

Answer (score 1):

What does it mean that the method *hides* the method from the base class?

```
class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base - Method1");
    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public void Method1() // DerivedClass.Method1() hides inherited memeber BaseClass.Method1(). Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Derived - Method1");
    }
}
```

Imagine if you've written the following:

```
var dc = new DerivedClass();
dc.Method1();
```

You compile and run this code, and the derived method is called. But now, *delete* `Method1` in `BaseClass`. The code still compiles and runs exactly the same.

`Method1` in `DerivedClass` *hid* the `Method1` method in `BaseClass` from anyone *using* `DerivedClass` directly (or any further derived instances)